# Add text to R mosaicplot

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

I am trying to add text to individual tiles within a mosaicplot built using the base R function. However, I cant determine the coordinates of each center tile.

And no, I need to limit it to the **mosaicplot** function and don't want to use the vcd package. The code below demonstrates the addition of text based on the knowledge of where it should go. How can I derive these coordinates?

```
require(stats) 
attach(Titanic)
mosaicplot(~  Sex + Survived, data = Titanic) 
text( .4,.6, "where to get this number ?",col = "red", cex = 2) 
text( .4,.1, "and how to find coordinates ?",col = "blue", cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: This was exactly one of the motivations for writing `vcd`. This computation is quite cumbersome, specifically if more than two variables are involved. Hence, my best recommendation is to reconsider using `vcd`. Or otherwise obtain the source code of `mosaicplot()` and hack your labels into that.

Comment: Thanks Achim, I have now adapted vcd.